# How to Concatenate Multiple Message as one at the delivery by NodeJs SMPP

Tags: node.js, sms, gsm, smpp

Hello im using Nodejs with farhadi node-smpp library to send Message through smpp v3.4 protocals and gsm library to split the message, In my case i have a long Message(More than 255 characters), when i split the message i want it to be delivered as single long message, but unfortunately it is delivered in parts. Here are my sample codes for sending the message

```
var info = gsm(text);
var concat_ref = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var part_id = 0;
info.parts.forEach(function(part){

  part_id++;
  var udh = new Buffer.allocUnsafe(6);
  udh.write(String.fromCharCode(0x5), 0); //Length of UDF
  udh.write(String.fromCharCode(0x0), 1); //Indicator for concatenated message
  udh.write(String.fromCharCode(0x3), 2); //  Subheader Length ( 3 bytes)
  udh.write(String.fromCharCode(concat_ref), 3); //Same reference for all concatenated messages
  udh.write(String.fromCharCode(info.sms_count), 4); //Number of total messages in the concatenation
  udh.write(String.fromCharCode(part_id), 5); //Sequence number ( used by the mobile to concatenate the split messages)


  session.submit_sm({
    source_addr:      from,
    destination_addr: to,
    message_payload: { udh: part.udh, message: part }
}, function(pdu) {
  console.log('sms pdu status', lookupPDUStatusKey(pdu.command_status));
    if (pdu.command_status == 0) {
        // Message successfully sent
        console.log(pdu.message_id);
    }
});

})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `message_payload` parameter (field name) as stated in the official SMPP's [specification](https://smpp.org/SMPP_v3_4_Issue1_2.pdf) to send messages longer than 254 octets.

`message_payload` definition:

> Contains the extended short message user data. Up to 64K octets can be
> transmitted.

The official document says:

> Applications which need to send messages longer than 254 octets should
> use the message_payload parameter. In this case the sm_length field
> should be set to zero.
>
> The short message data should be inserted in either the short_message
> or message_payload fields. Both fields must not be used
> simultaneously.

I made a test with **node-smpp**, and it works. No need to concatenate.

Comment: Do you have any working sample using node-smpp? @victor

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you mean by "i want it to be delivered as single long message".

But SMPP wise, what you are doing seems correct. Long messages are delivered in parts and they are concatenated by the terminal(phone) based on the three parameters : part_ref, part_number and total_parts. However, from my experience, the concatenation is not really standard across all devices. For instance, some devices don't wait long enough for all the parts to arrive and show incomplete messages or nothing at all.

You have 2 choices when sending concatenated sms via SMPP : One is what you used (UDH), but there are also TLV parameters dedicated for the 3 parameters. You could ask your SMPP provider about extra details on how they support the sending of concatenated messages.